# Need to do old fashioned input/output in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, input

I am new to Cocoa and need to capture input using scanf to run a program that requires input of four variables one at a time.

Is there any console, window class, canvas, memo class (as in delphi) that will llow me to do this.

Earl Cenac

Answer (score 3):

You can use stdio with Objective C, which is a complete superset of C.

If your program runs from a command line, you can just write it in C.

Answer (score 1):

Objective C is just a an extensions to C, and Objective C++ is an extension to C++. You can use scanf, or if you prefer you can use Objective C++ (rename your implementation files to end with .mm) and use C++ iostreams.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *password=@"rajan";
NSString *scanpass;
char currentpass[10];

NSLog(@"Enter your old password tp compare");
scanf("%s",currentpass);
scanpass = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:currentpass];
//if([password isEqualToString: @"rajan"])
if([password isEqualToString: scanpass])
    NSLog(@"Correct Password");
else 
    NSLog(@"Wrong Password");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NSScanner](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to parse the input, but as has already been said you use the C standard library to interact with stdin/stdout. I'd use -[NSString initWithUTF8String:] to get the conversion from c string to NSString.

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C is simply a set of extensions to C (and a supporting library and API in libobjc), so you have access to everything that any other C program would have. So, just use `scanf`.

To get the results into an `NSString`, use `+[NSString stringWithUTF8String:]` or (less probably) `+[NSString stringWithCString:encoding:]`.